# Wordpress - Post redirect to main category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website has posts with multiple categories. Today, I can access the post through two links:

URL 1 - mywebsite.com/**category-A**/post-name

URL 2 - mywebsite.com/**category-B**/post-name

However, when I access **URL 2**, it automatically redirects to **URL 1**. Is it possible to stop this auto redirect?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off Canonical URL Redirection, you can add the following code to your theme’s functions.php file.

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```